# TLS errors when using python-ldap to make modifications

Tags: python, python-ldap

Im currently having issues connection to `ldaps`. Connecting to non TLS/SSL on 389 works fine. However I am not able to make any modifications over this channel. I get an error `UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM: {'info': '0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A0FC0, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0\n', 'desc': 'Server is unwilling to perform'}`. Some googling suggested modifications need to be made over TLS/SSL.

So I attempted to make a connection over 636. This has proved to be troublesome. I have attempted to ignore the certerrors using `ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)' however, this hasn't helped at all.

I am constantly getting `SERVER_DOWN: {'info': 'SSLHandshake() failed: connection closed via error (-9806)', 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server"}`
below is the connection snippet. (I have confired 636 is open and have attempted on multiple DC's. I have all so tried various combinations on the connect string `ldap:\\server:port`, `ldaps:\\server`, `ldaps:\\server:port` etc)

I am including the code associated with the task that fails with the `UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM` error. This occurs even when using highly privleged accounts.

**Used WithOut TLS**

```
def changePassword(user_dn):
    for user in user_dn:
        new_password = pw_gen()
        unicode_pass = unicode('\"' + str(new_password) + '\"', 'iso-8859-1')
        password_value = unicode_pass.encode('utf-16-le')
        add_pass = [(ldap.MOD_REPLACE, 'unicodePwd', [password_value])]
        print user
        print new_password
        try:
            l.modify_s(user,add_pass) # `UNWILLING_TO_PERFORM:...'
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

**TLS Connection Attempt**

```
ConnectDC = 'ldaps://server:port'
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)
l = ldap.initialize(ConnectDC)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)

try:
    l.simple_bind_s('user', 'pass') # `SERVER_DOWN:...` 
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a password change? TLS over port 389 will work just fine for this. But that error message is in regards to a password restriction. In other words, you're trying to set a password on an account and the new password does not meet the password policy restrictions (length, complexity, etc). Or you might not be encoding the password properly (ie. UTF-16LE).

Comment: Yes indeed I am, however the password in question is well beyound the requirements enforced by the current Password policy. I will udpate my question to include the passwordchange function

Comment: Have you tried using `start_tls_s()`? That initiates TLS over port 389 after initializing the connection. The ldap uri would stay "ldap://" (without the s). You would still need to use the OPT_X_TLS_NEVER though.

Comment: I have attempted it before, however I will try again as per your suggestion.

Comment: `ConnectDC = 'ldap://host'
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEVER)`
`l = ldap.initialize(ConnectDC)
l.start_tls_s()`

Comment: This fails with `ldap.UNAVAILABLE: {'info': '00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090CF0, comment: Error initializing SSL/TLS, data 0, vece', 'desc': 'Server is unavailable'}`